# Facebook like button doesn't show in IE, only for one specific page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm managing a page for a client that has a like button on his page. The strange thing is that it doesn't show up in IE, while it does in other browsers. I use the iframe code of facebook:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=URLOFPAGE&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:auto; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When I use the url of my own facebook page the like button works (even in IE), but when I use the url of my client it doesn't. What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct that removing the country restrictions will work, but what is you can't do that due to a business requirement of your facebook page. It sounds like a bug with facebook's script to me.

Comment: With any restrictions on the target page, the like button will only show up if the user is logged in to Facebook in their browser. And that's not a bug, because otherwise FB has no way of determining if the user meets the restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem why the like button didn't show was because of the 'country restrictions'. Go to your page -> manage permissions and delete all country restrictions.

Now the like button will show on all computers, mobile phones, tablets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the length of your client's URL. I've found previously that the URL was simply too long. If they haven't claimed a unique URL (e.g. facebook.com/TheClientsName) then do that first and it should solve the problem.